# Issues with displaying GUI

Tags: java, swing, events, event-handling, components

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.
This program displays an online restaurant ordering menu.
I haven't written out the event handlers yet, however I'd like to be able to see if what im
doing is working for the program. 
I put the add components in a method called initComponents()
However I can't seem to call it in the main method.

Here is the code in its entirity:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class JameSimpsonP7 extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //Declare Food Objects

        //Appitizers
        Food artDuo = new Food("Artichoke Duo", 11.00, "A duo of fried artichoke hearts and cream cheese artichoke dip. Served with Ciabatta crisps. ");
        Food shrimpCocktail = new Food("Jumbo Shrimp Cocktail", 12.00, "Large ice cold shrimp served in a martini glass served with our house marinara sauce ");
        Food sliders = new Food("Kobe Sliders", 11.00, "Three bite sized kobe beef hamburgers served with french fries and house dill aioli.");
        Food crabStack = new Food("Mango Crab Stack", 13.00, "A tower of mango, cream cheese, and freash crab served with ciabatta crisps.");
        Food bisque = new Food("Tomato Bisque", 6.00, "A bowl of our famous house tomato bisque served with house made croutons.");

        //Entree's
        Food ribeye = new Food("Ribeye", 38.00, "Our succulent ribeye cut cooked to order. Served with a loaded baked potato and lobster mac and cheese.");
        Food surfTurf = new Food("Surf and Turf", 42.00, "A combination of our house prime rib cut and lobster cooked to order. Served with yorkshire pudding.");
        Food filet = new Food("Filet Mignon", 34.00, "Our house cut of filet mignon served with au jous and bacon and asperigus creamed corn.");
        Food nyStrip = new Food("New York Strip", 35.00, "A 12 oz. New York Cut steak strip cooked to your specification. Served with yorkshire pudding.");
        Food primeRib = new Food("Prime Rib", 29.00, "A 14 oz. cut of our prime rib. Cooked to your specification. Served with house potatoes.");
        Food charShirmp = new Food("Charbroiled Shrimp", 28.00, "Five of our large house shrimp grilled and served with a sweet corn polenta and asperagus.");
        Food halibut = new Food("Pan Seared Halibut", 34.00, "Freash caught halibut grilled and served with house vegetables and yorkshire pudding.");
        Food scallops = new Food("Ancho Peanut Dusted Scallops", 34.00, "Scallops seasoned with ancho peanut dust, grilled, and served with bacon and asperagus creamed corn.");
        Food romanChick = new Food("Roman Chicken", 24.00, "A grilled airline chicken breast served with a melange of house vegetables and sweet corn polenta.");
        Food salmon = new Food("Cedar Plank Salmon", 30.00, "Salmon smoked with our Cedar wood and lemon zest, served with a light pasta with a lemon caper buerre blanc sauce.");

         //Sides
        Food lobMacChz = new Food("Lobster Mac and Cheese", 8.00, "House made macoroni and cheese served with 4 oz. of pure lobster meat.");
        Food yorkPud = new Food("Yorkshire Pudding", 5.00, "A smoky pudding made with our house french bread and a smokey caper and pepper sauce.");
        Food crmCorn = new Food("Bacon and Asperegus Creamed Corn", 6.00, "A melange of bacon and asperegus with our house made creamed corn.");
        Food potatoes = new Food("Parmesean House Chive Potatoes", 5.00, "Our house mashed potatoes made with chives and parmesean cheese.");

        //Desserts
        Food chocCake = new Food("Chocolate Cake", 7.00, "An individual dark chocolate cake served with chocolate shavings and a chocolate fudge sauce.");
        Food carrotCake = new Food("Carrot Cake", 7.00, "Carrot cake with a cream cheese frosting and a sugar carrot on top.");
        Food strawShrtCak = new Food("Strawberry Short Cake", 7.00, "An American Classic! Shortbread soaked with strawberry sauce, topped with whipped cream, and stuffed with strawberries.");
        Food tiramisu = new Food("Tiramisu", 6.00, "A classic espresso and kahlua soaked lady finger cake served with chocolate shavings.");
        Food applePie = new Food("Stuffed Apple Pie", 5.00, "Our applle pie dumpling served with cinnamon dust and whipped cream.");
        Food bananaCrm = new Food("Banana Cream Pie", 6.00, "An individual pie crust stuffed with banana slices, vanilla pudding, and topped with a mirangue cream.");

        JameSimpsonP7 frame = new JameSimpsonP7();
        frame.initComponents();


    }

    public JameSimpsonP7() {
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")                       
    private void initComponents() {

        northPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        titleLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        phoneNumLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        westPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        appitizerLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        appitizerPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        appList = new javax.swing.JList();
        entreeLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        entreePane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        entreeList = new javax.swing.JList();
        dessertLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        dessertPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        dessertList = new javax.swing.JList();
        southPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        addToOrderButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        eastPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        yourOrderLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        orderTextArea = new java.awt.TextArea();
        totalPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        delivaryCheckBox = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        carryoutCheckBox = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        subTotalLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        taxRateLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        totalPriceLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        calcButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        centerPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        detailPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        detailLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        detailTextArea = new java.awt.TextArea();
        specificationPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        pricePanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        priceLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        specificationLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        specificationField = new java.awt.TextField();
        sidesPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        sideLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        buttonPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        lobMacChzRadioButton = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        yorkPudRadioButton = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        baconAspRadioButton = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        parmPotRadioButton = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();

        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(800, 600));
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(800, 600));
        setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        northPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(250, 0, 50));
        northPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        titleLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trajan Pro", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        titleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        titleLabel.setText("James American Bistro");
        northPanel.add(titleLabel, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        phoneNumLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        phoneNumLabel.setText("(405) 555-3213");
        northPanel.add(phoneNumLabel, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        add(northPanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        westPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 50));
        westPanel.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(260, 520));
        westPanel.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(260, 520));
        westPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(260, 520));
        westPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(6, 1, 1, 1));

        appitizerLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold", 1, 14));
        appitizerLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        appitizerLabel.setText("Appitizers");
        westPanel.add(appitizerLabel);

        appitizerPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        appList.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
            String[] strings = { "Artichoke Duo", "Kobe Sliders", "Jumbo Shrimp Cocktail", "Mango Crab Stack", "Tomato Bisque", "" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        appList.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        appList.addListSelectionListener(new javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {
                appListValueChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        appitizerPane.setViewportView(appList);

        westPanel.add(appitizerPane);

        entreeLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold", 1, 14));
        entreeLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        entreeLabel.setText("Entrees");
        westPanel.add(entreeLabel);

        entreePane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        entreeList.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
            String[] strings = { "Ribeye", "Surf and Turf", "Filet Mignon", "New York Strip", "Prime Rib", "Charbroiled Shrimp", "Pan Seared Halibut", "Ancho Peanut Dusted Scallops", "Roman Chicken", "Cedar Plank Salmon", " ", " " };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        entreeList.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        entreeList.setToolTipText("");
        entreeList.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        entreeList.addListSelectionListener(new javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {
                entreeListValueChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        entreePane.setViewportView(entreeList);

        westPanel.add(entreePane);

        dessertLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold", 1, 14));
        dessertLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        dessertLabel.setText("Deserts");
        westPanel.add(dessertLabel);

        dessertPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        dessertList.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
            String[] strings = { "Chocolate Cake", "Carrot Cake", "Strawberry Shortcake", "Tiramisu", "Stuffed Apple Pie", "Banana Cream Pie", " " };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        dessertList.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        dessertList.addListSelectionListener(new javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {
                dessertListValueChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        dessertPane.setViewportView(dessertList);

        westPanel.add(dessertPane);

        add(westPanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        southPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 55));
        southPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        addToOrderButton.setText("Add to Order");
        addToOrderButton.setToolTipText("");
        addToOrderButton.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        addToOrderButton.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        addToOrderButton.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        addToOrderButton.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(10, 25));
        addToOrderButton.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(10, 25));
        addToOrderButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(10, 25));
        addToOrderButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                addToOrderButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        southPanel.add(addToOrderButton, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(southPanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        eastPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 50));
        eastPanel.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(260, 520));
        eastPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(260, 520));
        eastPanel.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(eastPanel, javax.swing.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        yourOrderLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        yourOrderLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        yourOrderLabel.setLabelFor(orderTextArea);
        yourOrderLabel.setText("Your Order");
        eastPanel.add(yourOrderLabel);

        orderTextArea.setEditable(false);
        eastPanel.add(orderTextArea);

        totalPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 50));
        totalPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(6, 1));

        delivaryCheckBox.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 55));
        delivaryCheckBox.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold", 1, 11));
        delivaryCheckBox.setText("Delivary - $4.00");
        delivaryCheckBox.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
        delivaryCheckBox.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                delivaryCheckBoxActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        totalPanel.add(delivaryCheckBox);

        carryoutCheckBox.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(240, 0, 55));
        carryoutCheckBox.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        carryoutCheckBox.setText("Carryout - Free!");
        totalPanel.add(carryoutCheckBox);

        subTotalLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold", 0, 11));
        subTotalLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
        subTotalLabel.setText("Sub Total :");
        totalPanel.add(subTotalLabel);

        taxRateLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold", 0, 11));
        taxRateLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
        taxRateLabel.setText("Tax Rate : ");
        totalPanel.add(taxRateLabel);

        totalPriceLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold", 0, 11));
        totalPriceLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
        totalPriceLabel.setText("Total Price :");
        totalPanel.add(totalPriceLabel);

        calcButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 55));
        calcButton.setText("Calculate");
        calcButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                calcButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        totalPanel.add(calcButton);

        eastPanel.add(totalPanel);

        add(eastPanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        centerPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        centerPanel.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(370, 520));
        centerPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(370, 520));
        centerPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(3, 1));

        detailPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(250, 250, 250));
        detailPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        detailLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold", 1, 11));
        detailLabel.setText("Details");
        detailPanel.add(detailLabel, java.awt.BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        detailTextArea.setEditable(false);
        detailPanel.add(detailTextArea, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        centerPanel.add(detailPanel);

        specificationPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(250, 250, 250));
        specificationPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(4, 1));

        pricePanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(250, 250, 250));
        pricePanel.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        priceLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold", 1, 11));
        priceLabel.setText("Price:");
        pricePanel.add(priceLabel, java.awt.BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        specificationPanel.add(pricePanel);

        specificationLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold", 1, 14));
        specificationLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        specificationLabel.setText("Specifications");
        specificationPanel.add(specificationLabel);

        specificationField.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.TEXT_CURSOR));
        specificationField.addTextListener(new java.awt.event.TextListener() {
            public void textValueChanged(java.awt.event.TextEvent evt) {
                specificationFieldTextValueChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        specificationField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                specificationFieldActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        specificationPanel.add(specificationField);
        specificationField.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("");

        centerPanel.add(specificationPanel);

        sidesPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(250, 250, 250));
        sidesPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        sideLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold", 1, 11));
        sideLabel.setText("Add Sides");
        sidesPanel.add(sideLabel, java.awt.BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        buttonPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(250, 250, 250));

        lobMacChzRadioButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold", 0, 11));
        lobMacChzRadioButton.setText("Lobster Mac and Cheese - $8.00");
        lobMacChzRadioButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                lobMacChzRadioButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(lobMacChzRadioButton);

        yorkPudRadioButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold", 0, 11));
        yorkPudRadioButton.setText("Yorkshire Pudding - $5.00");
        yorkPudRadioButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                yorkPudRadioButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(yorkPudRadioButton);

        baconAspRadioButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font(
                "Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold", 0, 11));
        baconAspRadioButton.setText(
                "Bacon and Asparagus Cream Corn - $6.00");
        baconAspRadioButton.addActionListener(
                new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                baconAspRadioButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(baconAspRadioButton);

        parmPotRadioButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font(
                "Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold", 0, 11));
        parmPotRadioButton.setText("Parmesean House Chive Potatoes - $5.00");
        parmPotRadioButton.addActionListener(
                new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                parmPotRadioButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(parmPotRadioButton);

        sidesPanel.add(buttonPanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        centerPanel.add(sidesPanel);

        add(centerPanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }                      



    //declare variables used in handlers
    final double TAX_RATE = 2.9;
    public double orderTotal;
    public double [] yourOrderPrices = new double [10];
    public String [] yourOrderName = new String [10];
    public String details;
    public double price;



    //Handler Functions
    private void calcButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    }                                          

    private void delivaryCheckBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    
        orderTotal += 4.00;
    }                                                

    private void lobMacChzRadioButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {     
    }                                                    

    private void specificationFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {      
    }                                                  

    private void yorkPudRadioButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    }                                                  

    private void appListValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                     
        detailTextArea.setText("TEST");
    }                                    

    private void dessertListValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                         
        detailTextArea.setText("TEST");
    }                                        

    private void specificationFieldTextValueChanged(java.awt.event.TextEvent evt) {                                                    
    }                                                   

    private void addToOrderButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    }                                                

    private void baconAspRadioButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
    }                                                   

    private void parmPotRadioButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    }                                                  

    private void entreeListValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                        
    }                                       

    // GUI Componenet Declaration                 
    private javax.swing.JButton addToOrderButton;
    private javax.swing.JList appList;
    private javax.swing.JLabel appitizerLabel;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane appitizerPane;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton baconAspRadioButton;
    private javax.swing.JPanel buttonPanel;
    private javax.swing.JButton calcButton;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox carryoutCheckBox;
    private javax.swing.JPanel centerPanel;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox delivaryCheckBox;
    private javax.swing.JLabel dessertLabel;
    private javax.swing.JList dessertList;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane dessertPane;
    private javax.swing.JLabel detailLabel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel detailPanel;
    private java.awt.TextArea detailTextArea;
    private javax.swing.JPanel eastPanel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel entreeLabel;
    private javax.swing.JList entreeList;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane entreePane;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton lobMacChzRadioButton;
    private javax.swing.JPanel northPanel;
    private java.awt.TextArea orderTextArea;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton parmPotRadioButton;
    private javax.swing.JLabel phoneNumLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel priceLabel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel pricePanel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel sideLabel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel sidesPanel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel southPanel;
    private java.awt.TextField specificationField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel specificationLabel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel specificationPanel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel subTotalLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel taxRateLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel titleLabel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel totalPanel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel totalPriceLabel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel westPanel;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton yorkPudRadioButton;
    private javax.swing.JLabel yourOrderLabel;

    //Food class handles food objects
    private static class Food {

        private String name;
        private double price;
        private String details;

        public Food(String name, double price, String details) {
            this.setName(name);
            this.setPrice(price);
            this.setDetails(details);
        }


        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }

        public double getPrice(){
            return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(double price){
            this.price = price;
        }

        public String getDetails(){
            return details;
        }

        public void setDetails(String details){
            this.details = details;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to call it from the main method, as it is already called from within the constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't created any displayable window such as a `JFrame` in which for the derived `JPanel` `JameSimpsonP7` can be displayed. Also calling the `JameSimpsonP7` variable `frame` may be the source of your confusion.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JameSimpsonP7 panel = new JameSimpsonP7();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I made the adjustment and my GUI finally runs.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written this code, calling `frame.initComponents()` would be redundant. This is because, upon constructing the `JameSimpsonP7` object, the method initComponents is already called, as you can see in the constructor method

```
public JameSimpsonP7() {
    initComponents();
}
```

Because I'm not sure exactly what error you're getting (wasn't stated in the question), this is the only fix I noticed.